# how we can add the background color in full sheet using axlsx gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, axlsx

Here is my code and I want to add background color in full sheet not in a specific row or column.

```
xlsx_package = Axlsx::Package.new
   wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Basic Worksheet") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row ["First Column", "Second", "Third"]
  sheet.add_row [1, 2, 3]
end
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: i suppose you can use loop to go through all the rows and set bg_color simply. no need to wait for a one unique solution for that.

Comment: @ Abhinay, your saying is right but my requirement is quite different from this. First I need to set a background color for all sheet and a different color for each data row.